# check whether a number is bleak or supported in efficient way

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

1. Given a number how to recognize if it is bleak or supported by some number in efficient manner?
2. Given an array of numbers, how to check efficiently whether each number is supported with in the 
   array or bleak if not supported with in the array?

Brute force : Find binary equivalent, count number of 1's and search for it in the array.

**About Bleak and supported numbers:**

For each number, count the number of ones in its own binary representation, and add this count to itself to obtain the value of the number it supports. That is, if j is the number of ones in the binary representation of m, then m supports m+j.

Example:`number eight (1000 in binary) supports nine, whereas nine supports eleven.`

However, in this way not all the numbers get supported; some are left without support, and these numbers  are called bleak. For example since one supports two, two supports three and three supports five, there is no number less than four, which would support four, so four is bleak.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: you need a `popcount()`?

Comment: @EOF: what popcount()?

Comment: `popcount()` is the usual name for a function that counts the set bits in a binary number. So to calculate supported_number(x), you'd do `popcount(x)+x`.

Answer (score 1):

If `n` is not bleak, it must be supported by a number in the range `n-ceil(log2(n))` to `n-1`. This gives a very small range you have to check. For the array, first sorting the array then using the same principle should give you an efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Denote `a` as the given array and `count(x)` as the number of 1 bits in x.

Question 2:

1. Iterate through the array and save the the number `a[i] + count(a[i])` into a binary search tree. Time: O(n log n)
2. Iterate through the array and output "Supported" if a[i] is in the binary search tree and "Bleak" otherwise. Time: O(n log n)

Note: a[i] is the current element at the iteration.

Comment: say x = 4, how do you know in O(log x) time whether x is supported or bleak according to your answer?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood question 1.